# Let $X \subseteq V$ be convex and $r, s, t \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $r, s, t>0$ and $r+s+t=1$. Show that $r u+s v+t w \in X$, $\forall u, v, w \in X$

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis

**My attempt**

Let $u, v, w \in X$ and $r, s, t > 0$ be such that $r + s + t = 1$. Consider the point $p = ru + sv$. We want to show that $ru + sv + tw \in X$.

Since $X$ is convex and $u, v \in X$, then for all $r, s > 0$ with $r + s < 1$, the linear combination $ru + sv$ is in $X$. Therefore, the point $p = ru + sv$ is in $X$.

Now, since $r + s + t = 1$, then $r + s = 1 - t$. So we can write $p$ as:
$$ p = ru + sv = (r+s)\left(\frac{r}{r+s}u + \frac{s}{r+s}v\right) $$

Therefore, we have:
$$ (1-t)p + tw = (1-t)(ru + sv) + tw $$

Since $\frac{r}{r+s}u + \frac{s}{r+s}v$ is a convex combination of $u$ and $v$, and $p$ is in $X$, and since $tw$ is a combination of a point $w \in X$ with a positive scalar, by the convexity of $X$, the linear combination $(1-t)p + tw$ must also be in $X$.

Therefore, the correct and complete expression is:
$$ (1-t)(ru + sv) + tw \in X $$

This completes the proof that $X$ is convex.

**Doubt**

In this resolution, I used the normalisation process to prove that $p \in X$, is this a valid process? Is there any other way I could separately prove that $ru + sv \in X$? Also, is the strategy of first checking if $ru + sv \in X$ and then moving on to $ru + sv + tw\in X$ valid?

Comment: Quote from https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: *For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.*

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p$ need not be in $X$.
As a concrete example, take $  X = [3, 4]$, $r =  s = t = \frac{1}{3}, u=v=w = 3$.
Then $ p = \frac{1}{3} \times 3 + \frac{1}{3} \times 3 = 2 \not \in X$.

Your solution is wrong because you used a different (and wrong) definition of "X is convex ...".
The condition is not $ r+s < 1$, bur rather $ r+s = 1$.
Note that we allow for $ r, s = 0 $, unlike what you stated.